# Accessing Remote Computer using java

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

I am using a virtual machine,and I want to run the batch file which is in other virtual machine(which is protected,but I know the credentials).
The tool which I am having is "**RAD**" alone.

Also I cant able to download anything because no admin privilage.

So kindly help me to write a java program to resolve this task.
The reason why is that, I need to run so many batch files stored in many other machines.
Kindly let me know if any further requirements are needed!!!

Comment: Are the two virtual machines connected to the same Network/Domain?  Are the two machines both Windows and which versions?  Do you know if remote desktop is enabled on the other virtual machine?  Why do you need admin privileges to download a tool?  The answers to these questions are needed to determine what method to try.